# Make and email address lowercase

Tags: c#, openid

So I'm trying to create a lower case version of an email however, I'm wondering if culture will have an affect.

```
public class aspnet_Membership
{  
    //...
    public Email { get; set; }
    public LoweredEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Currently I'm just calling .ToLower() like so:

```
this._user.aspnet_Membership.Email = value;
this._user.aspnet_Membership.LoweredEmail = value?.ToLower();
```

I know there are casing issues in some languages,  I haven't investigated the emca spec for email addresses.   Is this safe to do, or do I need to use CultureInvariant or will there always be cases where domain names will transform wrong etc?

Comment: This doesn't deserve a downvote, it is a clearly written, legitimate question. Some people just lack imagination. My opinion is that you should only send communications to the email address, **verbatim**, that the user entered and verified, do this and casing or `CultureInfo` becomes a non-issue. At any rate, if I were going to do this, `LoweredEmail` would be a `readonly` property that returns the desired transform of `Email`.

Comment: Yeah, personally I don' t think that loweredemail should have even made it into the OpenId standard.   We're not using it for anything currently but I have a task to set it.  Now I'm confused on the behavior, because domain names support some accented chars etc

Comment: Then my question would be, does OpenId provide guidance regarding this issue? ...since they want to be all trendy and stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure, I'll have to see if I can make an Inquiry against them.  I'm going to first try to verify if there is a domain name that will change, with the lower invariant

Comment: Use `ToLowerInvariant`. It’s extremely unlikely that the OpenID specification would mandate that the lower-case transformation should depend on if the application runs in a German, Swedish, whatever locale. At least with `ToLowerInvariant` you get a consistent behavior.

Comment: @ckuri I'm more worried that the conversion could change the domain name, and if for some reason in the future the application is using the lowered version we could expose security emails ect to other users

Answer (score 1):

> You can use the following approach for making lowercase all the letters of each word by using `CultureInvariant` :

```
text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? string.Empty : 
    text.ToLower(new CultureInfo("en-US", false));
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm more concerned on whether its possible that, lowering a domain name could change it to another domain, because of how some characters are transformed. 
 As a suggested edit: `text?.ToLower(new CultureInfo("es-ES", false));`

Comment: I think by using en-US as culture variant, you can fix the problem. On the other hand, you can also use `RegEx` for checking email or domain value in `viewmodel`.